# Bundles overridden by Karaf FeatureService.installFeatures()

Tags: jackson, apache-karaf, karaf

We are using Karaf 4.1.7, and while creating Karaf distribution we package Jackson core 2.9.7 bundle within karaf system directory.

And in one of our applications we use Jackson-core 2.9.2 bundle which is added to a feature. When we install this feature using Karaf FeatureService.installFeature(featureName) it overrides the existing 2.9.7 bundle instead of adding a new bundle. We were expecting that both the versions would be available or coexist.

And when I type 'list' command can see the overridden bundle version 2.9.2 instead of 2.9.7. And another strange thing is when we checked through bundleContext.getBundles() I still see 2.9.7 bundle. And in the bundle cache I see version0.1 folder in which the new 2.9.2 jar is present.

Could any one provide pointers on how to resolve this or what we are missing here. Please let us  know if you need more details.

Thank You, 
Dheeraj

Answer (score 0):

Both jackson-core bundles of different versions should be installed in the karaf instance and likely get resolved. It does not get *overidden*. If you call the `list` (which gets resolved to `bundle:list` by default) shell command it does print out all bundles having an OSGi start level equal or greater 50. The first line does shows this:

```
karaf@root()> list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
```

So the first installed bundle might get skipped. Decreasing the bundle start level threshold to 0 via command line

```
bundle:list -t 0
```

all installed bundles of the karaf instance will get listed.

Regarding the result of `bundleContext.getBundles()`: only one version of another bundle can be bound and thus the first/original bound bundle version gets listed for the certain bundle (context).